# Remote User Interviews - Setting up for minimum technology problems

Tags: user-interviews

I'm trying to arrange some remote user interviews and while I am Tech Savvy myself, I can't assume my interview subjects will be. Does anyone have a tried and tested set-up and method.

Ideally, I'd prefer a video chat session that I can record but here are my concerns.

Calls to interviewees from desktop to desktop can result in issues like microphone/video not working correctly due to it not being set up correctly their end. Also, they may not even have access to a computer.

Appear.in requires no additional software download but it does not work on Safari or IE browsers. They may not have other browsers installed.

Hangouts is good but requires the additional steps of downloading and setup of software for the interviewee.

Facetime excludes non-Apple interviewees.

Whatsapp video from mobile to mobile may work, but how reliable is the built-in iPhone screen recording software for recording?

Facebook messenger video chat works from desktop and phone but I feel like asking for someone's Facebook details may seem a bit odd.

Skype requires downloading additional software and having an account which seems like a big ask for non-Skype people.

Anything else I have missed?

Comment: Your question is very broad and borders on software recommendations, both of which are to avoided in this stack exchange.

Comment: To echo what Rob E has already said: this is too broad and there are too many gaps to fill in before we can answer this question. We just don't know enough about your requirements to help you - The chances are that if you start trying to figure out a proper set of requirements for this then you'll be able to solve it on your own.

Answer (score 1):

> Does anyone have a tried and tested set-up and method.

There's no silver bullet I know of other than to just be prepared. Regardless of what software you use, <del>have a plan</del> focus on what you can control:

- Send the participant instructions on how to prepare ahead of the call - tell them what link to download, what browser. Hopefully you've done as much homework on your participants ahead of time and you can tee this up.
- Assume they won't have had a chance to look at the instructions and then plan for at least the first 10 minutes of the hour to be devoted to technical overhead as you figure those things on the call...always happens.
- Have a failsafe/backup plan for if the software doesn't work, like just defaulting back to speaker phone and recording it with Quicktime or whatever on your end

> Calls to interviewees from desktop to desktop can result in issues like microphone/video not working correctly due to it not being set up correctly their end.

Correct. Even if you send them instructions ahead of time, you have to hope they follow through and even then you can't rule out connectivity issues on either end, or solar flares or whatnot.

> Also, they may not even have access to a computer.

See the list, this is something to find out ahead of time if possible. Just exchange phone numbers, put it on speaker and record it with your computer (after you get their consent of course.)

Comment: As Mike Tyson said, everyone has a plan until they get punched in the face :) But yeah - plan, plan, plan.